# Get and set granular GPO permissions

Tags: powershell

We are attempting to write a script to set permissions on a large set of GPO. The trouble we are having is all of the methods we have found online do not allow setting custom or special permissions. The below are methods we have used so far that are not producing the results we need.

**Method 1** - XML Report

```
$xmlReport = $gpo.GenerateReport('xml')
```

This command only returns the name of the trustee. Also includes some properties that I am uncertain if pertinent.

**Method 2** - ADSI/LDAP object

```
$GPOACLList = $GPOObjSec.GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
```

This method returns the group and the permissions but not in a granular fashion. "FileSystemRights" returned are "FullControl" for ACLs that I know are considered custom/special with granular permissions.

**Method 3** - Get-GPPermission

```
Get-GPPermission $gpoWithAppSpec -all | select -ExpandProperty permission
```

Returns permissions similar to those available to Set-GPPermission such as "GpoApply", "GpoEditDeleteModifySecurity", "GpoRead". Again, these are not granular permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all acls set on a gpo:

```
$DomainDN = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
(get-acl "ad:CN={GPO-GUID},CN=Policies,CN=System,$($DomainDN)").Access
```

Additionally to the acls on the ad object, there are permissions on the GPO in the sysvol folder:

```
$DnsRoot = (get-addomain).DnsRoot    
(get-acl "\\$DnsRoot\sysvol\$DnsRoot\Policies\{GPO-GUID}\").Access
```

There most likely is way to automatically create the sysvol-permissions based on the ad-object permissions baked into gpmc, but I do not know how to access it.

Update: I found out how to do it.

Use [IGPMGPO::MakeACLConsistent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gpmgmt/nf-gpmgmt-igpmgpo-makeaclconsistent):

```
$GPOGUID = 'my-guid'
$DnsRoot = (get-addomain).DnsRoot
$gpm = New-Object -ComObject GPMgmt.GPM
$gpmconstants = $gpm.GetConstants()
$gpmdomain = $gpm.getdomain($DnsRoot, "", $gpmconstants.UsePDC)
$gpmgpo = $gpmdomain.getgpo($GPOGUID)
if (!$gpmgpo.IsACLConsistent()) {
  $gpmgpo.MakeACLConsistent()
}
```